# Subtract 2 random numbers, unable to compare

Tags: random, input, numbers, compare

I'm new to coding so it's probably a stupid mistake but I just can't figur out what is going wrong. I made an email form with a function to check if it's a human sending the message.
They have to answer a simple math question generated with random numbers.
But when I try to check if the input is correct, something goes wrong.

The relevant parts of the code I'm using:
First I generate two random numbers, calculate the correct outcome and turn the answer into a variable:

```
$number = array( mt_rand(1,5), mt_rand(6,10) );
$outcome = $number[1] - $number[0];
$human      = $_POST['message_human'];
```

The part where to put the answer:

```
<label for="message_human">
<input type="text" style="width: 44px;" placeholder="…" name="message_human"> + <?php echo $number[0];?> = <?php echo $number[1];?>
</label>
```

The part to check if the answer is correct, and perform action:

```
if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != $outcome) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human);  //not human!

    else {              //validate presence of name and message
        if(empty($message)){
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

    } else {            //ready to go!
        $message = "http://url.com" . $url . "\n\n" . $message;
        $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);

        if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent);
        else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent);
        }
    }
} else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
```

I keep getting the "not human error".
I tried making $outcome an array and all kind of operators but nothing works.
When I give the $outcome a fixed value like = "2"; everything works fine, but I want it to be a random number. Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code right, you are not saving those random numbers, right?
So how could you get the correct comperison, when you send the answer to a previous generated set of random numbers when you just generate new ones?

A possible solution may be to save those values in a session variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['outcome'] = $outcome;
```

and compare it later with this variable, but make sure it is not overwritten by a new generated set of random numbers.

```
if($_POST['message_human'] == $_SESSION['outcome']){
    //correct
}
```

Comment: It took me a while but i finally got it working with your help.

Comment: Sorry, new comment, could only edit it for 5 minutes..

Had to change a couple more things:
    
    $_SESSION['outcome'] = $outcome;

had to put it underneath the rest of the email-script.
furthermore I needed to check if there was already a SESSION running, using at the top of the page:

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();

Did the trick for me. Thanks a lot for your help!

I upvoted you, but my vote does not yet count..